# how to print year-month in proper order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I need to output data in a file in the following format: year-month,val. it should be sorted on year-month
for example:

```
2016-1,5
2016-7,1
2016-9,3
2016-11,4
2016-12,2
```

But, I am getting:

```
2016-1,5
2016-11,4
2016-12,2
2016-7,1
2016-9,3
```

the code is as follows:

```
for k,v in sorted(dictD.items()):
           drow = [k,v]
           writer.writerow(drow)
```

How to get the desired output?

Comment: This is why months and days are usually written with leading zeros.

Comment: The dates are sorted lexographically. you can use a key in the sorted function to get desired output.

Comment: Then `dictD` is not a dictionary.

Comment: If you're getting that error, how are you getting the incorrect output that you show?

Comment: thanks @Barmar. Problem solved. Pls explain the answer.

Comment: If you have comments about an answer, you should post them below the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 2):

Split the date at the hyphen and convert it to a tuple of numbers rather than strings.

```
for row in sorted(dictD.items(), key = lambda(x): map(int, x[0].split('-'))):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

`x` is the `(key, value)` tuple returned by `items()`, so `x[0]` is the key, which is a date like `'2016-1'`. `split` splits this into the tuple `('2016', '1')`, and `map(int)` converts that to a sequence of integers `(2016, 1)`. Using this as the sort key will order them numerically instead of lexicographically.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary is keyed by the YYYY-MM string and the value is the number after the comma, you can add a key argument to your `sorted()` call.
The key func could be:

```
lambda item: item[0][:5] + ('0' if len(item[0]) < 7 else '') + item[0][5:]
```

So your sorted call goes from:

```
sorted(dictD.items())
```

to:

```
sorted(dictD.items(), key=lambda item: <the rest from above>)
```

This leaves sorting by strings, but by adding the leading zero to the one-digit month, things come out as you want.

As a side note, you can pass a named function in as the key. You're not limited to using a `lambda` call.

When you pass things into `sorted()` without specifying a sorting algorithm, a default sort order is used. Dicts are sorted by keys (as strings), and tuples are sorted by tuple elements, starting with the first. For you, your `.items()` call produces a list of tuples (or at least close enough), with the key as the first element of the tuple, so the tuples get sorted by the dict keys as strings, ignoring any potential numeric value. By padding the leading zero to the one-digit months, the dates can be properly sorted as strings. The lambda call does just that -- it pads that extra '0' when necessary to allow the sorting to occur with the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a direct code, but I couldn't make it more simple so you may try to change the format of the month like this:

```
dictD = {'2016-1':5, '2017-7':1,'2016-9':3, '2016-11':4, '2016-12':2}
formatedKey = [list(dictD)[i].split('-')[0]+'-'+'{:02d}'.format(int(list(dictD)[i].split('-')[1])) \
               for i in range(len(list(dictD)))]
dictD2 = dict(zip(formatedKey, list(dictD.values())))
for k,v in sorted(dictD2.items()):
           drow = [k,v]
           print(drow)
```

I didn't use the writer, but I hope this helps.